# D lang enum type safety in comparison

Tags: enums, d

This situation is prone to bugs:

```
enum A{x=0};
enum B{y=0};

if (A.x == B.y) {
    writeln("Indeed.");
}
```

I.e comparing enum vals of different enums... happens to me a lot by mistake.

How can I make those enums type safe? i.e. make dmd at least warn me that i'm comparing 2 different enums?

I understand that both values are upcasted to 'int' before the comparison.

Is there a way without creating a new type to help me with this?

edit: the official DMD bug report relating to this issue: https://issues.dlang.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6227 (PR: https://github.com/dlang/dmd/pull/6444)

Answer (score 1):

As an extension to Adam D. Ruppe's solution, you could use a generic compare:

```
bool compare(T)(T a, T b) if (is(T == enum)) {
    return a == b;
}
```

At least this way you don't have to write a compare for every enum type.
It may not be ideal, but I don't know that you can override opEquals for enum types, and even if you could, I'm not sure I would want to. The fact that named enums can behave as their base types can be useful -- this unrestricted comparison is an unfortunate side-effect.

Comment: Where is it useful? I.e. where is doing this implicitly useful?

Comment: It is useful whenever you want to compare two enums, but throw an error when the enum types do not match. It will work for any enum type, so you don't have to define a new `compare` for each enum, but you do have to remember to use `compare` instead of `==`

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the last sentence: 'The fact that named enums can behave as their base types can be useful...'

Comment: Ah, I was thinking of something like this: `enum Paths : string { imageDir = "content/image/", fontDir = "content/fonts/", ... }`. Later on you may call `loadBitmap(Paths.imageDir ~ "icon.png")`. Now that I think of it, though, I'm not coming up with a good example of that behaviour applying to `==`

Answer (score 1):

A last solution is to use a custom types and operator overload. This is really if you want to use the `==` operator:

```
import std.stdio;

struct ExtendedEnumeration(E) if (is(E==enum))
{
    E e;
    alias e this;
    bool opEquals(Rhs)(Rhs rhs){
        static if (is(Rhs == typeof(this)))
            return rhs == e;
        else static if (is(Rhs == E))
            return rhs == e;
        else
            assert(0, "unsupported type for comparison argument");
    }
}

void main(string args[])
{
    enum A{x}
    enum B{y=0}
    ExtendedEnumeration!A a; 
    ExtendedEnumeration!B b;
    writeln(a == b);
}
```

And you have strong type safeness. This returns

> core.exception.AssertError@C:...\temp_0186F968.d(13): unsupported type for comparison argument

indeed...

You could also returns `false` if rhs type doesn't match...but I think you get the principle.

Answer (score 0):

Just spitballing but you *could* write a compare function and use it instead of the `==` operator. Enum type checking on function parameters is more strict:

```
enum A{x}
enum B{y=0}

bool compare(A a, A b) {
        return a == b;
}

void main() {
        import std.stdio;
        A a = A.x;
        if (compare(a, B.y)) {
            writeln("Indeed.");
        }
}
```

test100.d(11): Error: function test100.compare (A a, A b) is not callable using argument types (A, B)

that kinda sux tho.